# How to check if logic board is actually got replaced

Tags: macbook-pro, logicboard

I have Macbook pro 15" early 2011 and my GPU died a couple of weeks ago. I contacted Apple service center about the costing and they said a whooping 1000 USD to replace the board. From one of my friend I got contact of former apple technician and he said he will change the logic board for half the price.

After a week he returned my macbook saying he had replaced the logic board. Now I am little confused if he really had changed the logic board or get it repaired? Because the serial number on logic board is same as previous.

I know this question is asked before here but I am not able to get a straight answer from there.

Can any apple technician confirm if Apple replace the logic board do they provide the same serial number on new logic board?

Comment: Apple still has a repair program for your issue for free: [MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)!

Comment: I am in India. I tried asking the same to apple guys and they said they have stopped this program and my mac was already out of warranty.

Comment: Even choosing the Indian page they still mention the 31, Dec 2016 as ending date: *The program covers affected MacBook Pro models until December 31, 2016*

Comment: Now I am thinking why I haven't checked the date on this page.. seems the logic board got replaced for free and I gave around 600 USD to a fraud. 
But still what should be the case serial number should not get changed with new logic board?